# How do I restructure the comment html in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am building a theme and want to restructure the HTML output of the comments in a post. In `comments.php`, it uses `wp_list_comments()` to output the comments. What is the filter hook I need to use to change the layout of the comment HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways:

1. Custom Callback Function, takes care how a comment renders.
2. Custom Comment Walker Class, takes care how entire comment list renders.

I suggest to modify the callback one.

1. Find at `comments.php` where the comments list renders.

```
wp_list_comments(
  array(
  'callback' => 'my_custom_comment', // our custom comment callback
  )
)
```

2. Create the callback, either `functions.php` or whatever your structure is.

```
function my_custom_comment( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
  // Here you render your custom comment based on parameters above.

  // IMPORTANT:
  // The markup here requires an opening <li> or <div> tag
  // depending on how is configured on your $args, but not
  // a closing tag, cause it's closed by `Walker_Comment`.
  // See the class for more details.

  // Example:
  /*
  <li class="comment">
    <article class="comment-body">
      ...
    </article>
  */
  // no closing tag for li because this comment may have other `children` inside this `<li>` tag.
}
```

See how WordPress handles it at `html5_comment` method: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_comment/

Test it and expand it yourself.